# Avoid repetition in writing an expression in VBA Excel coding

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have written a code in VBA Excel, a part of which is repeated several times in the entire code. for example:

```
sheets("A").range("A1").select
...
sheets("A").range("B2").value
...
sheets("A").range("C1").Copy
...
```

How can I define the expression `sheets("A")` at the beginning of the code as `ShA` instead of writing it several times?
Of course, I used the following method, but unfortunately it did not work:

```
Dim ShA as string
Set ShA = "sheets(""A"")"
...
ShA.range("A1").select
...
ShA.range("B2").value
...
ShA.range("C1").Copy
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to define it as a string. The problem is that you are trying to "alias" a string to be expanded out, it is something which might work in shell languages but not in more object oriented languages

What you need to do is work with *objects*.

Instead of trying to alias a string you need to create a new *object* that is the worksheet you want to look at.

```
Dim ShA As Worksheet    ' define as a worksheet object, not a string
Set ShA = Sheets("A")   ' set our new object to point at the worksheet we want
```

Now you can use the `ShA.range("A1").select` and so on as you expect.

You were actually very close in the syntax of what you needed to do, you just made a mistake in trying to get VBA to expand out your string instead of creating objects that you could point at the thing you were trying to simplify.